# Can promise body execute before following line

Tags: javascript, typescript

I think it is just too early in the morning for me to be thinking properly but if I have something like this:

```
const promise = someAsyncFunctionReturningAPromise().then(() => {
    cache.delete(promiseKey, promise); // LINE A
});
cache.set(promiseKey, promise); // LINE B
```

Do I need to worry that line A runs before line B or can I be guaranteed line B will run first? `cache.set` is a synchronous method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the implementation is compliant with the standard, the callback passed to `then` is always executed asynchronously. From the [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then#Return_value)

> The handler function (onFulfilled or onRejected) then gets called **asynchronously** (as soon as the stack is empty).

Or directly from the [Promise spec](https://github.com/promises-aplus/promises-spec#the-then-method)

> onFulfilled or onRejected must not be called until the execution context stack contains **only platform code**
>
> Here "platform code" means engine, environment, and promise implementation code. In practice, this requirement ensures that onFulfilled and onRejected execute asynchronously, after the event loop turn in which then is called, and with a fresh stack.

Given the callback is always called async (even if the promise is already resolved), the `set` call should occur before the delete `delete` call inside the callback.